# Query with two NOT IN subqueries

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have a query with two NOT IN on two subqueries:

```
SELECT u.feedbackid
  FROM user_feedback u 
 WHERE u.feedbackid NOT IN ( SELECT feedbackid 
                               FROM user_feedback_sent) 
   AND NOT IN (SELECT feedbackid 
               FROM user_feedback_received)
```

The query throws an error on the second NOT IN saying incorrect syntax.

Comment: Very stupid mistake :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the column name which shuold **NOT** be in the second subquery. This will probably works as you need:

```
SELECT u.feedbackid
FROM   user_feedback u 
WHERE  u.feedbackid NOT IN (SELECT a.feedbackid 
                            FROM user_feedback_sent a) 
AND    u.feedbackid NOT IN (SELECT b.feedbackid 
                          FROM user_feedback_received b)
```

Identation its always a good practice to implement when writing SQL code.

Hope it helps

Comment: @SergiuTripon . . . This is a correct answer both to your question and to what appears to be the intent of the query.